# The inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}(z)z^{-1}\log(z).$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

For a work I need to evaluate the following integral: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{uz}e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}\left(z\right)z^{-1}\log\left(z\right)dz,\ c>0,\,u>2$$ where $\mathrm{Ei}\left(z\right)$ is [the exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html). I know that $$\mathfrak{L}^{-1}\left(z^{-1}\log\left(z\right)\right)\left(u\right)=(-\log\left(u\right)-\gamma)1_{u>0}$$ where $\gamma$ is [the Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), so my idea was to find the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}\left(z\right)$ and then to use the convolution theorem. I found that $$e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}\left(z\right)=PV\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-uz}}{1-u}du\tag{1}$$ so my question is:

> Can I use the convolution theorem even if the integral in $(1)$ exists only in the sense of the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)? In other words, can I write $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{uz}e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}\left(z\right)z^{-1}\log\left(z\right)dz=PV\int_{0}^{u}\frac{\log\left(t\right)+\gamma}{u-t-1}dt?$$

I don't know if it is a standard property or is a idiocy. I searched in my textbooks but I didn't find anything like that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you explain $\mathfrak{L}^{-1}\left(z^{-1}\log\left(z\right)\right)\left(u\right)=-\log\left(u\right)-\gamma$ ? (you forgot something like a $1_{u > 0}$)

Comment: @reuns Sorry, there was a typo! About the ILT, I found it at page 980 of the following book https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Integral-Equations-Second-Edition/Polyanin-Manzhirov/p/book/9781584885078

Comment: But for $\Re(z) > 0$ : $\displaystyle e^{-z} \text{Ei}(-z) =-\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-(u+1)z}}{u}du=-\int_2^\infty \frac{e^{-uz}}{u-1}du$ and $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}^{-1}[e^{-z} \text{Ei}(-z)](u) = -\frac{1_{u > 2}}{u-1}$. The principal value comes when you look at $\Re(z) < 0$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I don't get it. I have to invert $e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}(z)$, not $e^{-z}\textrm{Ei}(-z)$ and I'm not sure I can use the convolution since the integral exists in terms of PV.

Comment: Ah ok for $\text{Ei}(z)$ you are right. In that case, why not look at $\Re(z) < 0$ ($c < 0$) to make everything convergent ?

Comment: @reuns Unfortunately I have to take $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0.$

Comment: Yes but you can do the switch of the domain of convergence at the end, after the convolution. That's why we need some details about $\mathfrak{L}^{-1}\left(z^{-1}\log\left(z\right)\right)\left(u\right)=-\log\left(u\right)-\gamma$

Comment: @reuns I see what do you mean, it is a good idea, thank you. However, do you know if the convolution holds even if we consider the PV?

Comment: Yes it should, assuming you meant $(\log (u) + \gamma) 1_{u <0}$ ! That's why I need to see the steps

Comment: @reuns Ok I see. I found this formula in a book but I think you are right, it should be $(\log(u)+\gamma)1_{u>0}$. In my problem I have to consider $u>2$ but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$\because\mathcal{L}_{z\to t}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\textrm{Ei}(z)\ln z}{z}\right\}$

$=\mathcal{L}_{z\to t}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\gamma\ln z}{z}+\dfrac{\ln^2z}{z}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^{n-1}\ln z}{n!n}\right\}$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series)

$=\mathcal{L}_{z\to t}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\gamma\ln z}{z}+\dfrac{\ln^2z}{z}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{z^n\ln z}{(n+1)!(n+1)}\right\}$

Contains the term $\ln z$

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is correct and can be made rigorous through the use of distributions. If
$$(f, \phi) = \int_0^\infty (-\ln u - \gamma) \phi(u) du, \\
(g, \phi) = \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_0^\infty \frac {\phi(u)} {1 - u} du$$
($f$ is just a regular distribution), then
$$\mathcal L[f] = \frac {\ln z} z, \\
\mathcal L[g] = e^{-z} \operatorname{Ei}(z), \\
\mathcal L[f * g] = \frac {\ln z} z e^{-z} \operatorname{Ei}(z).$$
The convolution is defined as
$$(f * g, \phi) = (f \otimes g, (x,y) \mapsto \phi(x + y)) = \\
(f, x \mapsto (g, y \mapsto \phi(x + y))).$$
$f*g$ is a functional that can be identified with the ordinary function $h(u)$ defined by your formula on any interval not containing $u = 1$.

Further, the inverse transform exists in the sense of ordinary functions, which means that $f*g$ doesn't have a singular component, and this also holds:
$$\mathcal L[h] = \frac {\ln z} z e^{-z} \operatorname{Ei}(z).$$
$h(u)$ has a singularity of the order $\ln^2$ at $u = 1$.